# Sharing UserDefaults between main app and Widget in iOS 14

Tags: ios, iphone, widget, homescreen, ios14

I am writing a widget for iOS, seems UserDefaults is not accessible in the widget, I added app group as following, still it's nil:

```
let prefs = UserDefaults(suiteName:"group.myco.myapp")
```

Still when I try to read something from `prefs` which I set in the main app, it's nil here.

Comment: are you using UserDefaults in a same manner in the main app? I mean: UserDefaults(suiteName:"group.myco.myapp")

Comment: and are you sure your group name is set everywhere it should be set?

Comment: I have the same problem and yes I am sure group name is correctly set in both.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll need to add the AppGroup capability to the widget target. Select the project, then select the widget target, go to the Signing & Capabilities tab, and click the `+ Capability` button. Then choose `AppGroup` and configure it with your group.

Answer (score 2):

As @Ilya Muradymov commented blow

You need to set data for corresponding group `UserDefault` first if you want to get the data between widget and container app:

```
 //object-C     
 [[NSUserDefaults.alloc initWithSuiteName:@"group.com.your.groupname"] setObject:mObject forKey:@"xxxxxxxx"];
 //swift
 UserDefaults(suiteName:"group.com.your.groupname").set(mObject, forKey: "xxxxxxxx")
```